# Vim bugzilla plugin?

Tags: vim, bugzilla

Does anyone know of any vim bugzilla plugins? Would be really nice to use bugzilla from vim, and avoid launching browser/eclipse. Is anyone writing one, and would like some help?

Answer (score 2):

Well, ... there is [GitZilla](http://www.theoldmonk.net/gitzilla/), a [plugin](https://github.com/gera/gitzilla) for Git-Bugzilla integration. I have no idea how it works, but it might be a good starting point for either usage, or starting to write your own.